# Upload Image file from app Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, file-upload

I am trying to upload image file to my server. Below screen shows call through postman.

With **KEY :** *"image"* and **Value :** *123.png [image file]* in form-data Body.

[image]

I want to implement the same in my app using swift. I tried different solution but dint find a proper solution.

I am a selecting image with help of UIImagePicker:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) 
            {
                let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                uploadImage(image: image!, url: "profile_image/")
            }
```

I call uploadImage function to upload image.

```
func uploadImage(image: UIImage, url: String) {
        let urlString = "http://example.com/path/"+url
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let token = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "token") as? String
        request.addValue("Token "+token!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!.base64EncodedData()
        //let postString = "image=\(imageData))"
        //request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let imgDict = ["image": imageData]

    do {
        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(imgDict)
        print(jsonBody)
        request.httpBody = jsonBody
    } catch let jsonError {
        print(" Parsing Error: "+jsonError.localizedDescription)
    }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Image upload API Error: "+error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                print(data)
                let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(BasicResponseParameter.self, from: data)
                print(responseData)

                if responseData.success {
                    print("Image uploaded")
                }
                else {
                    print("Image upload API Failed : "+responseData.message!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        popAlert(title: "FAILED", message: responseData.message!, owner:self)
                    })
                }
            } catch let jsonError {
                print("Image upload API JSON Error :"+jsonError.localizedDescription)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you encode (when sending the image to your server) and decode (when querying the image back) your image into `base64` format

> To encode

```
let img = /// this is your image 
let encodedString =   UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)?.base64EncodedString()
```

> To Decode:

```
let data_from_response = /// from your response 
let decodeData = Data(base64Encoded: data_from)
```

Since you are sending a `dictionary` over your request body, you will need to convert your `dictionary` to a `json`

```
guard let imgDataString = String.init(data: encodedString, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return } 

let imgDict = ["image": imgDataString ] 

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: imgDict, options: .prettyPrinted)

request.httpBody = jsonData
```

**Side Note** Avoid `implicit optional unwrapping` meaning `!`, either use `if let` or `guard` statements

Comment: Thank you very much Lamar for replying :), i encoded the Image with .base64EncodedData(),  i m getting "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." error

Comment: Lamar, i am worried whether i  sending KEY & VALUE properly. Are key and value in proper format/manner/way? @Lamar

Comment: did you properly unwrap your image ?

Comment: where to unwrap image? i have shown all my code to you.

Comment: check the answer update you'll see how you should send your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Lamar, i wraped the image as you asked! You can see it in above updated question. However, i am still facing "Image upload API JSON Error :The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." JSON Error!!

Comment: you still haven't change Token to Bearer just like I suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157174/discussion-between-nikdange-me-and-lamar).